# npm installation cannot use squid proxy

Tags: npm, proxy, squid

I am trying to do the npm installation with squid transparent proxy on a client. My squid server is 172.21.243.84:3128. Both the client and server use centos 7.
On the client, I set the proxy using:

```
export https_proxy='https://172.21.243.84:3128'
export http_proxy='http://172.21.243.84:3128'
```

then I run "npm install npm",
I got error like:

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npm.taobao.org/npm failed, reason: write EPROTO 139980905441152:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-04-20T10_46_23_058Z-debug.log
```

Then I checked the squid log,got a lot of "400" info below:

```
1587379583.046      0 172.21.29.52 TAG_NONE/400 4112 c %AD;%B2O%19%8C%F7%87%DDW%A7F%06%AAB0H%1E%98 - HIER_NONE/- text/html
1587379728.415      0 172.21.29.52 TAG_NONE/400 4495 NONE error:invalid-request - HIER_NONE/- text/html
........
```

But if I use "npm install npm --proxy http://172.21.243.84:3128", it works perfectly.

My squid configuration is:

```
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8     # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12  # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16 # RFC1918 possible internal network
acl localnet src fc00::/7       # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10      # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

#
# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
#
# Deny requests to certain unsafe ports
http_access deny !Safe_ports

# Deny CONNECT to other than secure SSL ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

# Only allow cachemgr access from localhost
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

# We strongly recommend the following be uncommented to protect innocent
# web applications running on the proxy server who think the only
# one who can access services on "localhost" is a local user
#http_access deny to_localhost

#
# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
#

# Example rule allowing access from your local networks.
# Adapt localnet in the ACL section to list your (internal) IP networks
# from where browsing should be allowed
#http_access allow localnet
#http_access allow localhost
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/squid.allowed.sites.txt"
http_access allow allowed_http_sites
# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all

# Squid normally listens to port 3128
http_port 3128  ssl-bump cert=/etc/squid/cert.pem
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/squid.allowed.sites.txt"
acl step1 at_step SslBump1
acl step2 at_step SslBump2
acl step3 at_step SslBump3
ssl_bump peek step1 all
ssl_bump peek step2 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump splice step3 allowed_https_sites
ssl_bump terminate step2 all

# Uncomment and adjust the following to add a disk cache directory.
#cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 100 16 256

# Leave coredumps in the first cache dir
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

#
# Add any of your own refresh_pattern entries above these.
#
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

Anyone has idea about how to fix my squid to make it work for npm installation without using "--proxy"?

Thank you

Comment: What  operating system are you using?

Comment: What's the environment which you are trying to run this?